# Pass URL as parameter to action method

Tags: asp.net, url, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I pass an URL to another website as parameter to an action method?
For example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEgkUKCwi30

Something like this won’t work:

```
http://localhost:61596/MyController/MyAction?Url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEgkUKCwi30
```

Do I need to kind of encode the URL?

Comment: From where you want to send the parameter? View ??? how? Button/Links ?

Comment: Parameter is part of a menu item (used to build the application menu), stored in the database.
The menu gets rendered in partial view using some custom HTML helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode it, yes. There is a special utility for this, [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx):

```
string urlParam = Server.UrlEncode("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEgkUKCwi30");
```

If in the view, you can also use UrlHelper.Encode:

```
Url.Encode("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEgkUKCwi30")
```